# Speed up python's struct.unpack

Tags: python, performance, numpy, unpack, lidar

I am trying to speed up my script. It basically reads a pcap file with Velodyne's Lidar HDL-32 information and allows me to get X, Y, Z, and Intensity values. I have profiled my script using `python -m cProfile ./spTestPcapToLas.py` and it is spending the most amount of time in my `readDataPacket()` function calls. In a small test (80 MB file) the unpacking portion takes around 56% of the execution time.

I call the `readDataPacket` function like this (`chunk` refers to the pcap file):

```
packets = []
for packet in chunk:
    memoryView = memoryview(packet.raw())
    udpDestinationPort = unpack('!h', memoryView[36:38].tobytes())[0]

    if udpDestinationPort == 2368:
        packets += readDataPacket(memoryView)
```

The `readDataPacket()` function itself is defined like this:

```
def readDataPacket(memoryView):
    firingData = memoryView[42:]    
    firingDataStartingByte = 0    
    laserBlock = []

    for i in xrange(firingBlocks):
        rotational = unpack('<H', firingData[firingDataStartingByte+2:firingDataStartingByte+4])[0]        
        startingByte = firingDataStartingByte+4
        laser = []
        for j in xrange(lasers):   
            distanceInformation = unpack('<H', firingData[startingByte:(startingByte + 2)])[0] * 0.002
            intensity = unpack('<B', firingData[(startingByte + 2)])[0]   
            laser.append([distanceInformation, intensity])
            startingByte += 3
        firingDataStartingByte += 100
        laserBlock.append([rotational, laser])

    return laserBlock
```

Any ideas on how I can speed up the process? By the way, I am using numpy for the X, Y, Z, Intensity calculations.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Numpy lets you do this very quickly. In this case I think the easiest way is to use the [`ndarray`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.html) constructor directly:

```
import numpy as np

def with_numpy(buffer):
    # Construct ndarray with: shape, dtype, buffer, offset, strides.
    rotational = np.ndarray((firingBlocks,), '<H', buffer, 42+2, (100,))
    distance = np.ndarray((firingBlocks,lasers), '<H', buffer, 42+4, (100,3))
    intensity = np.ndarray((firingBlocks,lasers), '<B', buffer, 42+6, (100,3))
    return rotational, distance*0.002, intensity
```

This returns separate arrays instead of the nested list, which should be much easier to process further. As input it takes a `buffer` object (in Python 2) or anything that exposes the buffer interface. Unfortunately, it depends on your Python version (2/3) what objects you can use exactly. But this method is very fast:

```
import numpy as np

firingBlocks = 10**4
lasers = 32
packet_raw = np.random.bytes(42 + firingBlocks*100)

%timeit readDataPacket(memoryview(packet_raw))
# 1 loop, best of 3: 807 ms per loop
%timeit with_numpy(packet_raw)
# 100 loops, best of 3: 10.8 ms per loop
```

Comment: This resulted in ~30x increase in speed for that specific function. Thank you so much. :D

Comment: Went from 200 seconds to 3 seconds!

Answer (score 13):

Compile a `Struct` ahead of time, to avoid the Python level wrapping code using the module level methods. Do it outside the loops, so the construction cost is not paid repeatedly.

```
unpack_ushort = struct.Struct('<H').unpack
unpack_ushort_byte = struct.Struct('<HB').unpack
```

The `Struct` methods themselves are implemented in C in CPython (and the module level methods are eventually delegating to the same work after parsing the format string), so building the `Struct` once and storing bound methods saves a non-trivial amount of work, particularly when unpacking a small number of values.

You can also save some work by unpacking multiple values together, rather than one at a time:

```
distanceInformation, intensity = unpack_ushort_byte(firingData[startingByte:startingByte + 3])
distanceInformation *= 0.002
```

As [Dan notes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36797525/364696), you could further improve this with `iter_unpack`, which would further reduce the amount of byte code execution and small slice operations.

Comment: I'd suggest testing my `iter_unpack` method before being too certain it improves performance—it creates plenty of temporary objects, I think. Your method sounds more certain.

Answer (score 3):

For your specific situation if you can fit your loop into a numpy call, that'd be fastest.

With that said, for just the `struct.unpack` part -- if your data happens to native byte order, you can use `memoryview.cast`. For a `short` example, it is about 3x faster than naive `struct.unpack` without any change in logic.

```
In [20]: st = struct.Struct("<H")

In [21]: %timeit struct.unpack("<H", buf[20:22])
1.45 µs ± 26.5 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)

In [22]: %timeit st.unpack(buf[20:22])
778 ns ± 10.8 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)

In [23]: %timeit buf.cast("H")[0]
447 ns ± 4.16 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can unpack the raw `distanceInformation` and `intensity` values together in one call. Especially because you're just putting them into a list together: that's what `unpack()` does when it unpacks multiple values. In your case, you need to then multiple the `distanceInformation` by `0.002`, but you might save time by leaving this until later, because you can use [`iter_unpack()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html#struct.iter_unpack) to parse the whole list of raw pairs in one call. That function gives you a generator, which can be sliced with [`itertools.islice()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice) and then turned into a list. Something like this:

```
laser_iter = struct.iter_unpack('<HB', firingData[firingDataStartingByte + 4])
laser = [[d * 0.002, i] for d, i in itertools.islice(laser_iter, lasers)]
```

Unfortunately this is a little harder to read, so you might want to find a way to spread this out into more lines of code, with more descriptive variable names, or add a comment for the future when you forget why you wrote this…

Comment: Unfortunately I can't use Python 3. I am using Python 2.7.11. Do you know of another solution?